# oracle insert statement with c# forms wont work?

Tags: c#, oracle

I had make this small method to insert data from C# forms into my Oracle database. The code processed fine, but when I go to SQL Developer to check if the record has been inserted or not, I found nothing...

```
        public void conn2db()
        {
            try
            {
                string connstring = "data source=test_db;user id=system;password=password;";
                string statmentcmd = "insert into register_user (userid,username,pass,fullname,phonenum,gender,country) values (" + 1 + "," + textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox4.Text + "," + textBox5.Text + "," + radioButtonValue+ ","+comboBox1.Text+");";

                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring);
                conn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("connected to database");

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

                cmd.CommandText=statmentcmd;
                cmd.Connection=conn;
                OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

                MessageBox.Show(statmentcmd);

                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection closed");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should escape the strings or better, use parameters in your command.

Comment: Problem solved..its coused by TNS services was not running at the services

control panel >> system and secuirty >>adminstrative tools>>Computer Management >> services

but I am still had problem with insert command line

string statementcmd =  "insert into register_user (pid,username,pwd,fullname) values ("+'1'+"," + textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox4.Text + ")";
Error message number is ora-00984 column not allowed here

could anyone check it for me ?? is it double qoutes or single qoutes ?
or what is it please
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the command like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.CommandText = statmentcmd;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or more simply:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(statmentcmd, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: it will throw an exception

Comment: @xXghostXx What exception do you see?

Comment: @xXghostXx that exception indicates there's something wrong in your command string. I **strongly** suggest using a parameterized command instead. That makes it easier to catch errors in the SQL syntax and protects you from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

try change the Copy to Output Directory : Do notcopy

Comment: more explanation please ?

Comment: This answer is a start, but more information would make it a great answer not just for the person asking, but for others who may run into this problem.